# R: Intersect doesn't work to find out which homes are in which areas

Tags: r

I have two datasets.

One is a csv file, which has a listing of Airbnb in New York.
Is from that website: http://insideairbnb.com/get-the-data
And NY Zipcodes from that website: https://data.cityofnewyork.us/Business/Zip-Code-Boundaries/i8iw-xf4u/data?no_mobile=true

```
ny <- read.csv("NY/listings.csv")
zc <-  st_read("ZIP_CODE_040114/ZIP_CODE_040114.shp")
```

Now I would like to find out which listings lie on which zipcodes. I did that with st_intersects, but I doens't function

```r
nysf <- st_as_sf(ny)
nysf <- st_as_sf(nysf,'EPSG:2263')
zc <- st_transform(zc,2263)
st_intersects(nysf,zc)
```

But I got an error message

```r
st_crs(x) == st_crs(y) is not TRUE
```

But they are both in the same crs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are they though? On a test data set, doing what you seem to be doing to set the CRS doesn't change anything:

```
> nysf = st_as_sf(nysf, 'epsg:2263')
> st_crs(nysf)
Coordinate Reference System: NA
```

If you name the argument it works:

```
> ny = data.frame(x=1:10, y=1:10)
> nysf = st_as_sf(ny, coords=1:2, crs="epsg:2263")
> st_crs(nysf)
Coordinate Reference System:
  User input: epsg:2263 
  wkt:
```

Or use `st_crs(thing) = "epsg:1234"` to override a current CRS or set a new one (*without* transforming the coordinate values, which you need `st_transform` to do)